# Saving tiff file with GdPicture always adds the Tiff tag #254 (NewSubfileType) with a value of 2

Tags: c#, image-processing, tiff

I am using GdPicture 9. When I save an image it ALWAYS adds the tiff tag #254 of NewSubfileType and sets its value to 2.

I've confirmed the source image has a value of 0. I can't see why it's being set to 2 when I save it. Any ideas?

```
// load source.tiff into gdpicture
var id = p.oGdPictureImaging.CreateGdPictureImageFromFile("source.tiff");

// view tags
//  NewSubfileType = 0
for (int i = 0; i < p.oGdPictureImaging.TagCount(id); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"image 1 ----{p.oGdPictureImaging.TagGetName(id, i)} - {p.oGdPictureImaging.TagGetValueString(id, i)}");
}

// save source image as "dest.tiff"
p.oGdPictureImaging.SaveAsTIFF(id, "dest.tiff", TiffCompression.TiffCompressionCCITT4);

// load dest.tiff into gdpicture
var id2 = p.oGdPictureImaging.CreateGdPictureImageFromFile("dest.tiff");

// view tags
//  NewSubfileType = 2
for (int i = 0; i < p.oGdPictureImaging.TagCount(id2); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"image 2 ----{p.oGdPictureImaging.TagGetName(id2, i)} - {p.oGdPictureImaging.TagGetValueString(id2, i)}");
}
```

Comment: Caveat: I've never used GdPicture, and the last time I played with TIFFs was the 1990s.  It looks like `NewSubfileType` is a recent tag added (replacing the `SubfileType` tag).  GdPicture probably adds it to all the files it creates.  My guess is based on https://awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/newsubfiletype.html.  Does its existence break something in your app?  My experience with TIFF files taught me to ignore stuff I don't care about (in general)

Comment: @Flydog57 unfortunately, the receiver of these tiff files checks for this NewSubfileType and it must either not exist, or it must have a value of 0.

Comment: Hmm. That page describes the meaning. The value of 2 meaning that Bit 1 (and only that bit) is set. It's described as _Bit 1 is 1 if the image is a single page of a multi-page image (see the PageNumber field description); else the bit is 0._. Is that true? I see you are using CCITT v4 compression. Is this a fax image? Sorry, I'm just grasping at straws

Comment: @Flydog57 This is a multipage tiff. It is a concatenation of multiple scanned images from a scanner into one multipage tiff, yes.

Comment: With multi-page TIFF, the standard way is to have this tag with each page, where bit 1 is set to 1, which gives a tag value of 2. Its value can only be zero with single-page TIFF. If you wish to save "old-style" TIFF files without this tag, you can use an imaging library such as LEADTOOLS SDK (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). You simply set `RasterCodecs.Options.Tiff.Save.NoSubFileType = true` before calling `RasterCodecs.Save()`. If you'd like to try the SDK, you can download the free evaluation using [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).